# Insert a list of integers into a database column

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a list of integers into a column in a datatable. If I run the following code:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO my_datatable('Column 1') VALUES (?)", list_with_integers)
conn.commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO my_datatable('Column 1') VALUES (?)", list_with_integers)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've checked and made sure that all the elements of the list are integers and if I try to run

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO my_datatable('Column 1') VALUES (?)", [list_with_integers])
```

I get:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO my_datatable('Column 1') VALUES (?)", [list_with_integers])
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 559 supplied.
```

**Question:** How do I solve this issue and insert a list of integers into a column?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to the `executemany` method should be a sequence of tuples, so you should convert your list of integers to a sequence of 1-tuples:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO my_datatable('Column 1') VALUES (?)", map(lambda i: (i,), list_with_integers))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Isn't this very slow for large rows?

Comment: You can use the `map` function instead to avoid creating another large list. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant with very large datatables! Is this really the fastest way to insert data?

Comment: Why do you think it would be slow? And slower compared to what?

Comment: @Mr.President I think this is as fast as it can get with the given tools. In which way do you find it inefficient?